# Compare data using the year in a query

Tags: mysql

I have a data and they are recorded by each year, I am trying to compare two years( the past year and the current year) data within one mysql query

Below are my tables

Cost Items

```
| cid   |   items   |
| 1     |   A       |
| 2     |   B       |
```

Cost

```
| cid   | amount    |   year    |
|  1    |   10      |   1       |
|  1    |   20      |   2       |
|  1    |   30      |   1       |
```

This is the result I am expecting when i want to compare the year 1 and year 2. Year 1 is the past year and year 2 is the current year

Results

```
items   |   pastCost    |   currentCost |
 A      |     10        |       20      |
 A      |     30        |       0       |
```

However the below query is what i used by gives a strange answer.

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(ps.`amount`, '0') as  pastCost
    IFNULL(cs.`amount`, '0') as currentCost
FROM
    `Cost Items` b

LEFT JOIN 

    `Cost` ps 
ON 
    b.cID=ps.cID 
        AND 
    ps.Year = 1

LEFT JOIN 
    `Cost` cu 
ON 
    b.cID=cu.cID 
        AND 
    cu.Year =2
```

This is the result i get from my query

```
items   |   pastCost    |   currentCost |
 A      |     10        |       20      |
 A      |     30        |       20      |
```

Please what am i doing wrong? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your data makes no sense.  How do you distinguish rows 1 and 3 in the `cost` table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: the value in the `amount` column on rows 1 and 3 are different ? maybe ? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm missing something about your query; the SQL text shown can't produce that result.

There is no source for the `items` column in the SELECT list, and there is no table aliased as `cs`.  (Looks like the expression in the SELECT list would need to be **`cu.amount`**

Aside from that, the results being returned look exactly like what we'd expect. Each row returned from `year=2` is being matched with each row returned from `year=1`.  If there were three rows for `year=1` and two rows for `year=2`, we'd get six rows back... each row for `year=1` "matched" with each row for `year=2`.

If `(cid, year)` tuple was UNIQUE in `Cost`, then this query would return a result similar to what you expect.

```
  SELECT b.items
       , IFNULL(ps.amount, '0') AS pastCost
       , IFNULL(cu.amount, '0') AS currentCost
    FROM `Cost Items` b
    LEFT
    JOIN `Cost` ps
      ON ps.cid  = b.cid 
     AND ps.Year = 1
    LEFT
    JOIN `Cost` cu 
      ON cu.cid  = b.cid 
     AND cu.Year = 2
```

Since `(cid, year)` is not unique, you need some additional column to "match" a single row for `year=1` with a single row for `year=2`.

Without some other column in the table, we could use an inline view to generate a value. I can illustrate how we can make MySQL return a resultset like the one you show, one way that could be done, but I don't think this is really the solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve:

```
  SELECT b.items
       , IFNULL(MAX(IF(a.year=1,a.amount,NULL)),0) AS pastCost
       , IFNULL(MAX(IF(a.year=2,a.amount,NULL)),0) AS currentCost
    FROM `Cost Items` b
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT @rn := IF(c.cid=@p_cid AND c.year=@p_year,@rn+1,1) AS `rn` 
                , @p_cid := c.cid AS `cid`
                , @p_year := c.year AS `year`
                , c.amount
             FROM (SELECT @p_cid := NULL, @p_year := NULL, @rn := 0) i
             JOIN `Cost` c
               ON c.year IN (1,2)
            ORDER BY c.cid, c.year, c.amount
         ) a
      ON a.cid = b.cid
   GROUP
      BY b.cid
       , a.rn
```

A query something like that would return a resultset that looks like the one you are expecting. But again, I strongly suspect that this is not really the resultset you are really looking for.

**EDIT**

OP leaves comment with vaguely nebulous report of observed behavior: "**the above solution doesnt work**"

Well then, let's check it out... create a SQL Fiddle with some tables so we can test the query...

[**SQL Fiddle here** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3d7e/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3d7e/1)

```
create table `Cost Items` (cid int unsigned, items varchar(5));
insert into `Cost Items` (cid, items) values (1,'A'),(2,'B');
create table `Cost` (cid int unsigned, amount int, year int);
insert into `Cost` (cid, amount, year) VALUES (1,10,1),(1,20,2),(1,30,1);
```

And when we run the query, we get a syntax error. There's closing paren missing in the expressions in the SELECT list, easy enough to fix.

```
  SELECT b.items
       , IFNULL(MAX(IF(a.year=1,a.amount,NULL)),0) AS pastCost
       , IFNULL(MAX(IF(a.year=2,a.amount,NULL)),0) AS currentCost
    FROM `Cost Items` b
    LEFT
    JOIN ( SELECT @rn := IF(c.cid=@p_cid AND c.year=@p_year,@rn+1,1) AS `rn` 
                , @p_cid := c.cid AS `cid`
                , @p_year := c.year AS `year`
                , c.amount
             FROM (SELECT @p_cid := NULL, @p_year := NULL, @rn := 0) i
             JOIN `Cost` c
               ON c.year IN (1,2)
            ORDER BY c.cid, c.year, c.amount
         ) a
      ON a.cid = b.cid
   GROUP
      BY b.cid
       , a.rn
```

Returns:

```
  items   pastCost  currentCost  
  ------  --------  -----------
  A             10           20
  A             30            0
  B              0            0
```

Comment: Do u think, it will be good for me to write two separate queries for this, thus one query for the current year and the other for the past query? Wld this help, thus if there are no optimised solution

Comment: @NewBIe:  "doesnt work" is a vaguely nebulous description of the behavior you are observing.  Are you getting an error message? An unexpected resultset, empty result, too many rows? "doesnt work" just doesn't cut it as a reported issue.

Comment: Get used to nebulous with this one

Comment: The original query had 2 errors that needed fixed before any results. Then the results were A 10 10. A 30 30. B 0 0

Comment: But the OP was incapable of describing the business requirement of what to achieve so someone technical enough could do it

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks for this answer, I dont wanna just use your code in my system. I will be grateful if you could explain for me to understand better. Since I am a newbie in mysql i am finiding it difficult to understand some lines of your codes, although i am still studying it. I also think explaining it will help future seekers. Thnks for helping.

Comment: @NewBIe: I recommend you pull out just query for the inline view `a`. Just those eight lines between the parens... **`SELECT @rn ... ORDER BY c.cid, c.year, c.amount`**. The inline view `i` is just there to initialize some user-defined variables. We don't care what `i` returns; we only care that it returns one row, because of the JOIN operation. From the `Cost` table, get all rows with year=1 or year=2. Force those rows to be sorted, by (cid,year,amount). For each row, if `cid` and `year` match the `cid` and `year` from the *preceding* row, increment `rn` by 1. Otherwise, return 1.

Comment: @NewBIe: The inline view `a` is just assigning integer values 1,2,3 to column `rn` for rows with matching `cid` and `year`. Then, in the outer query, we can "match" rows from `year=1` with rows `year=2` on the `rn` value. We do that with a `GROUP BY` operation. We use a conditional expression in the SELECT list to "pick out" the `amount` for rows with `year=1`, we return either `amount` or a NULL value. And we use the `MAX` aggregate to pickout a non-NULL value. That whole rigmarole is just to create a column we can match on, to "match" one row for `year=1` with one row for `year=2`.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff noted in a comment, "your data makes no sense" because you don't have a column that distinguishes which row from `year=1` should be matched with which row from `year=2`. If you had a column in the `Cost` table like the `rn` column that is being generated by the query, we wouldn't have to generate it, and the query would be *much* simpler and *much* more straightforward.

Comment: Good Man. Thnks soo much. This is very helpful

Comment: @spencer7593 So it means when we have a column like in the rn, we would just ignore the eight lines of code in the parens? If Yes, can we create a column like the rn and strategically find a way to generate rn values in there?